# creating html nav-tabs dynamic in angular 6

Tags: html, angular, tabs, angular6

I am very new to angular 6, I have created tabs in HTML and I need to convert it in angular 6 and also make it dynamic. below is my HTML code-

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs side_nav" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="dashboard_li active">
     <a href="#one" class="coin_name" aria-controls="one" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"></a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="dashboard_li">
    <a href="#two" class="coin_name" aria-controls="two" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="one"></div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="two"></div>
</div>
```

I have converted it angular 6, below is my angular code -

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs side_nav" role="tablist">
  <li *ngFor="let wallet of coinwallet; let first = first;" [ngClass]="{firstItem: first}" role="presentation" class="accounts_li" [class.active]="selectedwallet===wallet">
    <a (click)="selectedwallet = coinwallet" aria-controls="one" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"></a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="one"></div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="two"></div>
</div>
```

Now I have two pints here -
1- how would I make tab-content dynamic according to tabs
2- Currently tabs are not working, as I am changing from one tab to another tab, tab-content always remain same, it's not changing according to the tab.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need to show/hide tab-content using `*ngIf` angular directive

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs side_nav" role="tablist">
  <li *ngFor="let wallet of coinwallet; let first = first;" [ngClass]="{firstItem: first}" role="presentation" class="accounts_li" [class.active]="selectedwallet===wallet">
    <a (click)="selectedwallet = wallet" aria-controls="one" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{wallet}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div *ngIf="selectedwallet === coinwallet[0]" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="one">wallet 1 content</div>
  <div *ngIf="selectedwallet === coinwallet[1]" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="two">wallet 2 content</div>
</div>
```

.ts:

```
  coinwallet: string[] = ['wallet1','wallet2'];
  selectedwallet = this.coinwallet[0];
```

[check working code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kmnstf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the link you've mentioned is working fine but when I edited that code according to my project needs, it's not working
export class AppComponent  {
  coinwalletTab: string[] = ['wallet1','wallet2'];
  selectedwalletTab = this.coinwalletTab[0];
  coinwallet: string[];
  selectedwallet: any;
  OnInit(){
    this.coinwallet = ['wallet1', 'wallet2'];
    this.selectedwallet = this.coinwallet[0];
  }

Comment: leave OnInit() blank and why did you declare 'selectedwallet: any'?

Comment: @NitishKumar show me your code somewhere like in stackblitz or jsfiddle or just update your question with your complete code.

Comment: how to create tab-content also dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than converting HTML tabs to Angular, You can directly user ng-bootstrap components which works very well with Angular and comes with lot of configurable options. below is a link for ng-bootstrap tabs

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs/examples

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But I have already created those tabs and if I change the tabs, I would have to change a lot of content so that won't be a solution